# Unable to execute dex error in console window

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I would like to build an app which uses HoloEverywhere. I import HoloEverywhere and ActionBarSherlock as described in this [manual](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse).

Then I create a new project, according to the following steps:

1. Create a new Android project
2. Right Click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Add, add both ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere
3. Change the Android Manifest to following

   `<application android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme"`
4. And change the MainActivity imports to `org.holoeverywhere.app.*`

import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

How when I run the "App", eclipse tells me this error in the console window:

> [2013-05-15 07:45:17 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex
>   files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>   [2013-05-15 07:45:17 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
>   Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove YourProject/libs/android-support-v4.jar.
ABS already have a this library, but older (r7 instead of latest r12).

You should manually replace support library from contrib/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/libs/android-support-v4.jar by HoloEverywhere/support-library/android-support-v4-r12.jar

Answer (score 0):

Steps : 
1. select the libs folder in the project and (click +R) 
2. choose build path 
3. in the libraries remove the android-support-v4